# RabbitMQ shovel losing messages (try to emulate network problems)

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I am building the cluster with RabbitQM servers . I use shovel plugin to deliver mesages from one rabbitmq to other (different machines)

It works fine . But i want to test how it will behave when no network connection between servers.

On each server i have local queue. I push messages to it and then shovel delivers a message to remote rabbitmq queue

To emulate network problems i did

```
iptables -D OUTPUT -d xx.xx.xx.xx -j DROP
```

to disable connection to remote server xx.xx.xx.xx

then i push message to local queue, it disappears from the queue but **is not on remote server**!
How can  it be? does shovel check if remote queue is available before remove a message from a queue?

How to make it to work correctly? I want shovel doesn't remove a message from q queue till ensured ti si delivered to remote queue.

Comment: Could you post the output of `rabbitmqctl list_channels`and `rabbitmqctl report`during the issue? create a gist with the outputs, if you can.

Comment: I already found the solution, posted below. Thanks

Comment: Nice trick to emulate packet loss - I'll be adding that one to my toolbox

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution for my problem.
I changed settings os a shovel.
There was the option

```
ask_mode,on_publish
```

I changed to

```
ask_mode, on_confirm
```

and it started to work correctly.